# Understanding callbacks and related lexical scoping

Tags: javascript, callback, lexical-scope

I am trying to understand callbacks via `setTimeout` function.
I have two sets of code :

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        (function(callback,i){
          setTimeout(function(){
            callback(i)
          }, 0);
         })(function(val){console.log(val)},i);
```

It works fine printing 1,2,3,.... 10

But when i am trying  to abstract `setTimeout`'s callback function as :

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        (function(callback,i){
          setTimeout(func, 0);
         })(function(val){console.log(val)},i);
        }
function func(){
    callback(i)
  }
```

It gives me error stating

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined
```

I know there is some issue with lexical scoping of declaration of that func function. But not able to comprehend the reason.
Please do help me understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is throwing reference error because, the function `func` it has a scope where there is no declaration for `callback`. You can fix it by passing the callback as a parameter to `func`.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  (function(callback, i) {
    setTimeout(func, 0, callback.bind(null, i)); //Pass the callback here as a parameter to func. 
                                   //(setTimeout can pass its >2 parameter as 
                                   //its callback parameter)
  })(function(val) {
    console.log(val)
  }, i);
}

function func(callback) { //receive the callback here and use it.
  callback();
}
```

Comment: the syntax u used to pass paramater to func is not supported in IE9 and earlier

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN IE 9 was dead! Microsoft stopped providing support for it.

Comment: Yes I know.but it's long to go so no single app will run on it

Answer (score 2):

`callback` is not defined within `func` . You can pass `func` as parameter to IIFE, use `Function.prototype.bind()` to pass `i` to `callback` : `func`

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  (function(callback, i) {
    setTimeout(callback.bind(null, i), 0);
  })(func, i);
}

function func(val) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very similar to the solution which OP is having. He used an anonymous function and you used bind. Both are same. But OP is asking why his second snippet is not working. What is the purpose of `func` in your code?

Comment: _"But OP is asking why his second snippet is not working. What is the purpose of func in your code?"_ `func` is passed as parameter to IIFE, which is referenced as `callback` within IIFE. `.bind()` does not call `func` : `callback`, but passes reference of `func`  : `callback` to `setTimeout` with `i` as parameter. Have you tried your posted solution ? , appears to log `11` to `console` ten times ?

Comment: I didn't notice that my code was printing 11 ten times. THanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

In `func` you don't have reference to `callback` that you declared in your IIFE.So,it start looking in current scope which is your `func` scope.then it try to find in global scope,it also not defined there.Finally it throws an error

You need to pass the refarence to this callback parateter refering the function to get rid of this error.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        (function(callback,i){
          setTimeout(func.bind(null,callback,i), 0);
         })(function(val){console.log(val)},i);
        }
function func(callback,i){
    callback(i)
  }
```